# Web Service dynamic invocation from WSDL at runtime

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I'm looking for a solution of dynamic web service client such as DII from JAX-RPC.

I need to generate a client from a WSDL.
But the WSDL is only known at runtime (so I don't have any available interface).

I had a look on JbossESB, JbossWS, JaxWS,JaxRPC, but I could'nt find anything that fits this requirements.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that WSIF can do exactly that but it requires JDK 1.3 uses old methods. I need to integrate this in a JDK 5.

Comment: dynamically means I assume after deployment of app. If so , suppose you have generated client how would you use it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is possible with CXF and some java reflection.

[jax-ws-dynamic-dispatch-with-cxf](http://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/08/jax-ws-dynamic-dispatch-with-cxf.html)

I'm personally looking for a solution for this + a dynamic server model as well.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

finding a *ready-made* solution to your problem is not easy. at least none exist AFAIK. due to the inherent, unknown complexity of the backing schema types associated w/ an operation's request and response, it's not possible to have such a solution.

however, putting together the correct tools, or using some open-source frameworks/libraries/tools you might be able to achieve something similar. basically you'll need to have a `WSDL4J` implementation, along with a schema parser like `XMLBeans` to get this working.

A tool which comes to my mind is `SoapUI`. it achieves something similar - user loads a WSDL at runtime and thereafter can execute operations. the source of this tool is also available for modification under LGPL [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/). you'll need to strip and salvage the core functionality that suits your need. or best, build one of your own :]